# Change text after the tag-name xml and php

Tags: php, xml, domxpath

I'm not able to change the text after the empty tag. How to solve?,

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book>
    <titlePart>
        <text>hi</text>
        <text>hello</text>
    </titlePart>
    <titlePart>
        <entryReference>hello refence <sref ref="BH002"/>, go go<sref ref="BH003"/> car</entryReference>
        <text>bank</text>
    </titlePart>
</book>';
```

How to fix my code using domdocument to change the text after the empty tag.

Final result!

```
<book>
    <titlePart>
        <text>teste 01</text>
        <text>teste 02</text>
    </titlePart>
    <titlePart>
        <entryReference>teste 03 <sref ref="BH002"/>texte 04 <sref ref="BH002"/>texte 05</entryReference>
        <text>teste 06</text>
    </titlePart>
</book>
```

My code!

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book>
    <titlePart>
        <text>hi</text>
        <text>hello</text>
    </titlePart>
    <titlePart>
        <entryReference>hello refence <sref ref="BH002"/>, go go<sref ref="BH003"/> car</entryReference>
        <text>bank</text>
    </titlePart>
</book>';

$array = array("teste 01", "teste 02", "teste 03", "teste 04", "teste 05", "teste 06");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result2 = $xpath->query('//book//titlePart//*|//entryReference[sref]//node()//*');

for ($i = $result2->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i --) {
    $nodePre = $result2->item($i); 

    if($result2->item($i)->getAttribute('ref')!="") {
        $tag = $result2->item($i)->getAttribute('ref');
        $varTexto = $array[$i];

    }else{
        $tag = $result2->item($i)->tagName;
        $varTexto = $array[$i];
    }

    $nodeDiv = $dom->createElement($tag, $varTexto); 
    $varNode = $nodePre->parentNode->replaceChild($nodeDiv, $nodePre);


}

       header("Content-type: text/xml");
       echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: You should describe your problem better at the beginning of your question. For example you write "empty tag" but it's not clear to which tag you refer to until the whole (and even if, I couldn't understand it for myself) question has been read. From the topic itself I'd say it should not be that hard, however I don't understand your question so there is not much help.

Comment: I am Brazilian.
And do not speak English correctly.
Can you help me?

Comment: You could name the "empty tag" - what is the tag-name? Another idea would be to provide the current and the wanted result next to each other in a way that they are more easy to compare. For exmaple, both in multiline.

Comment: You now have removed your code, you should still keep it, just make more clear where the concrete problem is ;) Sorry if I confused you.